# Let $x_0,x_1,...,x_k$ be $k+1$ vectors. Find the number of multiplications in $\|x_0\|^2_2+\dotsb+\|x_k\|_2^2$

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, matrix-norms

> Let $x_0,x_1,...,x_k$ be $k+1$ vectors, in which each $x_i (i =
>  0,1,...,k)$ has $n+i$ components ($n$ is a fixed value). Find the number of multiplications in $$\|x_0\|^2_2+\dotsb+\|x_k\|_2^2.$$

In the first vector, to calculate the norm-2 I have to do $n$ multiplications (for the squares). Then I have to do one more, for when I square the norm. So $n+1$ for the first vector, and then $n+2$ for the second, and so on, until $n+k+1$. This means I have

$$(n+1)+(n+2)+(n+3)+\dotsb+(n+k+1) = n(k+1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i$$
multiplications.
Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need to compute the intermediate norms (with square root) so you can save the additional multiplication, the "one more" you refer to.

Comment: It seems like you started from $x_1$, but your problem statement starts from $x_0$. so for the written proble it is $n+(n+1)+...+(n+k)=n(k+1)+\sum_{i=1}^k i$. Notice that there are n multiplications for $x_0$, one for each square of the elements; you don't actually have to multiply the square roots of the norm together

Comment: Square norm = sum of squares. So after you’ve summed the squares, you don’t need to square it again.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I do, because it's $||x||_2^2$ and not just $||x||_2$

Comment: I think the L2 norm is defined as $\sqrt{\sum y_i}$, no?